# Show element based on option value

Tags: angular

I need to show a div based on the selection, but it does not work as I expect.

Does anyone know how to do it?

```
<div class ="row">
  <div class="form-group col-md-6">
    <label for="make" class="control-label">Actualizar por:</label>
    <select [(ngModel)]= "optionUpdate" class="form-control" formControlName="optionUpdate">
        <option [value]="make">Marca </option>
        <option [value]="category"> Rubro </option>
    </select>
  </div>
  {{optionUpdate}}
</div>
<div class="row" >
    <div *ngIf = "optionUpdate === 'Marca'" class="form-group col-md-6">
    </div>
        </div>
<div class="row" >
    <div *ngIf = "optionUpdate === 'Rubro'" class="form-group col-md-6" >
    </div>
</div>
```

Thank you

Comment: Angular2+ or AngularJS? you tagged both

Comment: Have you tried to put `*ngIf` in the `<div class="row" >`?

Comment: Angular 5 and try with *ngIf in <div class="row" >

Comment: Can you post your component `ts` as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `select` you have the following options:

```
<option [value]="'make'">Marca </option>
<option [value]="'category'"> Rubro </option>
```

The possible values applied to the `ngModel` are "make" and "category" ; "Marca" and "Rubro" are just the visual part of the select component.

Therefore your conditions should be:

```
*ngIf="optionUpdate === 'make'"
*ngIf="optionUpdate === 'category'"
```

NB : you also forgot the single quote, your are databinding text, not a variable. `[value]="'make'"`

Comment: Yes but the problem persists. {{optionUpdate}} = undefined with select option

Comment: I found an other problem, I edited the response. You forgot the single quote when data binding your string.